# Python: Check facebook user access token expired or not

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using [facepy](https://facepy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/utilities.html#facepy.utils.get_extended_access_token) facebook api to fetch messages from my facebook account. I have got myself `long live access token` with validity of 60days using the API. Now, in my program before querying for message I want to check wether my token has expired or not and if expired fetch a new one.

I am using  [get_extended_access_token](https://facepy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/utilities.html#facepy.utils.get_extended_access_token) which also returns a datetime instance describing when token expires. Now I think it is not a effecient way to use `get_extended_access_token` because everytime I am going to query for new message it will also fetch the `access token`(I know it is same as before) but I think this is a overhead.

So, I googled and found that we can also use

```
https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token=INPUT_TOKEN&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

to [debug the token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/access-token-debug/)

So I supplied my `long live access token` instead of `INPUT_TOKEN and ACCESS_TOKEN` and it gave  me a json response:

```
{
   "data": {
      "app_id": XXXXX,
      "is_valid": true,
      "application": "YYYYY",
      "user_id": ZZZZZZ,
      "issued_at": 1349261684,
      "expires_at": 1354445684,
      "scopes": [
         "read_mailbox"
      ]
   }
}
```

Now if you look at `expires_at` field it is showing `1354445684 seconds` and when I tried to convert it into days/months it gave me `15676 days` and when I checked the same token in graph explorer using the debug option it showed

```
expires_at: 1354445684(about 2 months)
```

Now, what I don't understand is how `1354445684` is equivalent to `2 months` and how to achieve this in python.

Also comment on which is the better approach to check wether token has expired or not `API or using the facebook url`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Now if you look at expires_at field it is showing 1354445684 seconds and when I tried to convert it into days/months it gave me 15676 days

Then you’ve done (or understood) something wrong.

`expires_at` 1354445684 is a Unix Timestamp, and equals `Sun, 02 Dec 2012 10:54:44 +0000` translated into a human-readable date.

And that is pretty much two month from the `issued_at` timestamp 1349261684, a.k.a. `Wed, 03 Oct 2012 10:54:44 +0000`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used `1354445684/3600/24` which gave me `15676`. How did you came up with `Sun, 02 Dec 2012 10:54:44 +0000` ?

Comment: @Noob: Using `datetime` module we can get `datetime.fromtimestamp(1354445684 )` which results in `datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 2, 16, 24, 44)`

Comment: @Noob: A UNIX timestamp is seconds since the UNIX epoch, which is January 1st 1970.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you rely on exceptions to verify whether the token was valid instead of making a separate request to guarantee it:

```
from facepy import GraphAPI

graph = GraphAPI(token)

try:
    graph.get('me')
except GraphAPI.OAuthError:
    # Redirect the user to renew his or her token
```